# saving file in database using unpack php

Tags: php, image, pdf, unpack

```
$data = '0x'.unpack('H*hex', file_get_contents($tmp_name))['hex'];
```

Im trying to store file data into my database using the above code. Then I retrieve it and use it for download as

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename( $response->strFileName ).'"');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: '.$response->intSize);
echo $response->binFile;
```

where `$response->binFile` is the response from server the column where I stored the data from above code.

This works for pdf file but for image jpg/png it does not. The size of the image is smaller than the original file and I get the error

[image]

For image uploaded when I download it and open it. for PDF no problem

Original image is on the right the left image is the uploaded image to database then downloaded. Using the code above

[image]

I dont know if it is worth mention but the image I download has no dimension as shown below:

[image]

Original is on the right upload then downloaded on the left

Comment: What are you doing with that `unpack` code…?! Have you tried diffing the server response to the original file to see where the differences might be? Have you tried setting appropriate `Content-Type` headers?

Comment: the only difference is the size i will show a sample image property

Comment: @deceze please see updated OP. there is a small difference in the size of the image. But when in PDF it is same.

Comment: Well, even the size is identical. Again, use a diff program or hex editor to compare the actual file content. If that doesn't do it, be clearer about what we're looking at there. What's that program that tells you it "doesn't support this format"?

Comment: @deceze its an image viewer for windows the default one. let me check on your suggestions

Comment: @deceze the size for image is a bit smaller maybe thats the reason why? But I used  the same insert query for both image and PDF insert so I crossed that as reason

Comment: The "size on disk" is pretty irrelevant, only the size matters.

Comment: @deceze i tried opening in paint and it gets the error as well `this is not a valid bitmap file or its format is not currently supported`

Comment: @deceze i uploaded new image please check

Comment: Look. At. The. Contents. Of. The. Actual. File. With. A. Hex. Editor.

Comment: If I'd had to guess I'd say you're reversing the endianess of the bytes with your `unpack`; something that PDF readers somehow compensate for but image readers do not. So that goes back to my first comment: why `unpack` in the first place?

Comment: @deceze i know the cause now. There is a new line before the rendered data when I checked in notepad++ problem is I check everywhere but I dont know how the newline is generated. When I try to just out put the data in browser and removing the header there is no new line. When I add the header I generate a new line together with the data

Answer (score 0):

I used the below header. and fixed the problem

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-type: ".$response->strExtension.""); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
header("Content-length: ".$response->intSize.""); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($response->strFileName).""); 
echo base64_decode($response->binFile);
```